# How to rotate a 2D GameObject based on touch inputs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I want to find a way to rotate a 2D GameObject on the Z axis using touch and drag inputs. I have found a lot of solutions, but most of them are written in JavaScript don't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem this the code working I have tested it on my device and it was perfect:

```
public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
Vector2 pos;
private void Start()
{
    speed = 100;
}
private void Update()
{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector2 posInScreen = touch.position;

        if (Camera.current.ScreenToWorldPoint(posInScreen) != null)
        {
             pos = Camera.current.ScreenToWorldPoint(posInScreen);
        }
        float Xposition = pos.x;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Xposition*speed);



    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to unity documentation you can use Input.GetTouch();

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html

And drag handler:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html

Comment: I am a beginner at unity can you give me a functioning code

Comment: Actually I can't. If you take from me complete code of the solution then you won't learn anything. Try to learn this type of actions from a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pc8K_DVPgVM).

Comment: This [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbghT7MmckI42Gkp2cILkO2nRxK2M4NLo) can be more suitable for you. It has more detailed answer in this case.